# What is the getResourceAsStream() used only for reding inputs, how to write outputs

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So basically I have a file that the java code reads from and writes to.

BufferedReader works

```
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
            )
);
```

however, BufferedWriter doesn't work:

```
BufferedWriter bWrite = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(
                    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
                )
);
```

'OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream)' in 'java.io.OutputStreamWriter' cannot be applied to '(java.io.InputStream)'

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream`, that should give you a hint...

Comment: Please clarify ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Do you get compilation error, runtime exception, unexpected results? Usually in case of compilation error it points out cause of why compiler complains. Could you [edit] your question and include full error message in it?

Comment: Resources should be thought of as read-only anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one reads (input) and one writes (output) and since `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream` it does not make sense to pass it into a `Writer` because you cannot write to an `InputStream`, you can only read from it.